# I'm not able to add new agents not working: something is broken?

Tags: agent, wazuh

[![enter image description here][1]][1]On a fresh Ubuntu VPS, fresh install using docker, when trying to add a new agent, instead of "Close" option of that screen I get "Refresh" option. I then fill all the data, run the commands on the machines where agents suppose to run, nothing happens, if I press the refresh button it clears all options, if I go back to agents the list is empty.

On agent machine I get this in the logs:
wazuh-agentd: ERROR: (1208): Unable to connect to enrollment service at '[37.120.179.10]:1515'

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, you are having problems in the dashboard to be able to create the script to register a new agent, right?

If so, could you check the log files if something is wrong?

```
cat /var/log/wazuh-indexer/wazuh-cluster.log | grep -i -E "error|warn|critical"
cat /var/log/filebeat/filebeat | grep -i -E "error|warn|critical"
cat /var/ossec/logs/ossec.log | grep -i -E "error|warn|critical"

journalctl -u wazuh-dashboard
journalctl -u wazuh-manager
journalctl -u filebeat
journalctl -u wazuh-indexer
```

On the other hand, if you want to install a Wazuh agent, you can follow the official [documentation](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/index.html#installing-the-wazuh-agent).

Greetings,

Nicolas